# Using ng-model-options still Update model immediately

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

here is my the directives i attach to the input tag :

```
ng-model="user.firstname"  ng-required="true"   
ng-minlength="2" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'default blur '}"
```

the situation is:
I attach the ng-model-options to the input,but is still update the model immediately.

Is it okay when attach the validation and ng-model-options to the input tag at the same time?

If I wanna validate the field and update the model till I lose the focus on it,
what should I do??Am I right on this way?

THANKS!!

**SOLVED**

After,I uppgraded the angular.js version 1.2 to 1.3.

I got the effect I want.

Thanks to @user2341963 and the replier.

Comment: what version of angular are you using? `ng-model-options` is only from v1.3 I think. And it's updating immediately because you specified `default`. It should be `ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur '}"`

Comment: The version of angular.js  I'm using is 1.2.11.

Comment: Yes, upgrade to 1.3 or 1.4 if possible

Comment: Wow~It's solved!

Thank you @user2341963

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation: [ngModelOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)

> updateOn: string specifying which event should the input be bound to. You can set several events using an space delimited list. There is a special event called default that matches the default events belonging of the control.

You need to remove the default event.

Comment: I removed the default,and it still update immedaitely.So is it the issue of the version?

Comment: Thanks for reply!!

I solved the problem,It's a version issue.

After upgrade the version 1.2 to 1.3,it's work!